# Pushing a navigation controller on tapping a button

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, ios8, segue

In my Swift app, I have a navigation controller in which I have a table view controller that holds a list of "groups". I have a button on the top navigation bar that is supposed to add a new "group". On tapping the button, I need a view controller set up to add a new "group" to slide in from the right with a back button titled "Groups" in this new view's navigation bar.

I tried embedding a navigation view controller to my "new group" view controller and then using a push segue to transition on touch up inside of the bar button item in my "groups" view controller's navigation bar. This errors out with 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'

How can I best achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once your first view controller is embedded in a navigation controller, you don't have to embed subsequent view controllers in their own navigation controller - you simply push them in the context of the existing navigation hierarchy.

So you can remove the navigation controller from your "new group" scene and just establish a "push" segue (although this is deprecated and the "show" segue is preferred in iOS8) directly to that new scene from your button.

Comment: I expected that too, but when I right click+drag from the button to my new group controller, which is a table view controller, although it shows that a push segue has been established, tapping on the button does nothing. Here is what it looks like: https://copy.com/rEXe0NxbphrMGREi

Comment: Why is your groups table linked to another table view controller?  Wouldn't it go directly to the new groups scene? or is the other new groups scene I can see not in use.  I can't see from your screen shot,- if you select the + button, what is the "triggered segues" showing in the inspector?

Comment: Yeah that was an unused controller. I don't know what happened before, but I deleted the button and tried again, and that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a navigation controller, you likely do not want to create a new one.

Rather, from the current view controller, call `[self.navigation controller pushViewController:animated:]` passing an instance of the new "create group" view controller. If you set the `title` property of that view controller, it will be displayed in the navigation bar.